# EPiServer 7 (MVC) LinkItemCollection: add images to LinkItem collection?

Tags: episerver

I have a block which is going to display a `LinkItemCollection`. Each link has an image which belongs to it. Since clickable image isn't supported, I was wondering if anyone had a solution of how to couple the images and links together.

Maybe you could extend `LinkItem` and add an `Url` property to an image, any ideas?

This is EPiServer CMS 7 (MVC).

Comment: Is this a CMS 6 site?

Comment: @TedNyberg No, it is EPiServer CMS 7 (MVC).

Comment: Did a ContentArea work for you?

Comment: We decided to postpone it and look at some other issues first, before we tried this, since this way is pretty safe and easy to implement, and we have more risky stuff to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a **ContentArea** property instead of LinkItemCollection, and create a block type with properties for specifying link, image etc. Then add one block per link to the content area.

That also makes it a lot easier to add/remove/rearrange links with drag and drop.